# Como fazer uma busca em todos os elementos de um array no MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Tenho um documento MongoDB conforme o exemplo:

```
{
  "_id": "andresm",
  "username": "Andre Salesmo",
  "carros": [
    {"marca": "ferrari", "tipo": "coupe", "preco": "850000.00", "data_compra": "22/01/2015", "modelo": "512TR"},
    {"marca": "nissan", "tipo": "coupe", "preco": "542000.00", "data_compra": "12/05/2018", "modelo": "GTR"},
  ]
}
```

Eu gostaria de saber como eu consigo fazer uma busca filtrando pelo id e retornando todos os carros. Estou usando o pymongo como driver e estava tentando da seguinte forma e não obtive resultado:

```
cursor = mongo.db.movimentacoes.find(
 {"_id": usrId, "carros": {} }
```

Comment: Conseguiu fazer funcionar?

Answer (score 0):

Há um erro na sua query. Neste caso o método `find` recebe somente um parâmetro, um objeto, e vai utilizá-lo para fazer a query. Como está, o Mongo está buscando um documento com o id passado e em que carros seja um objeto vazio.

Altere para `mongo.db.movimentacoes.find({"_id": usrId})` (ou somente `mongo.db.movimentacoes.find(usrId)`, para fazer uma busca por ID).

Caso seu objetivo seja retornar somente `carros`, adicione mais um parâmetro ao método com `{"carros": 1}`, ex: `mongo.db.movimentacoes.find({"_id": usrId}, {"carros": 1})`.

Note que o mongo retorna implicitamente o ID. Para alterar esse comportamento é necessário excluílo com `{_id: 0}`, ficando `mongo.db.movimentacoes.find({"_id": usrId}, {"carros": 1, _id: 0})`.